# scala range split missing the last one

Tags: scala

I use scala Range.by to split an range to get an array, but it miss the last one for some special bucket num, for example 100. I am puzzled, and demo as following:

```
object SplitDemo extends App {
  val min = 0.0
  val max = 7672.142857142857
  val bucketNum = 100

  def splitsBucket1(min: Double, max: Double, num: Int) = (min to max by ((max - min) / num)).toArray
  def splitsBucket2(min: Double, max: Double, num: Int): Array[Double] = {
    val rst = Array.fill[Double](num + 1)(0)
    rst(0) = min
    rst(num) = max

    val step = (max-min)/num
    for(i <- 1 until num) rst(i) = rst(i-1)+step

    rst
  }

  val split1 = splitsBucket1(min, max, bucketNum)
  println(s"Split1 size = ${split1.size}, %s".format(split1.takeRight(4).mkString(",")))

  val split2 = splitsBucket2(min, max, bucketNum)
  println(s"Split2 size = ${split2.size}, %s".format(split2.takeRight(4).mkString(",")))

}
```

the output is following

> Split1 size = 100,7365.257142857143,7441.978571428572,7518.700000000001,7595.421428571429
>   Split2 size = 101,7441.978571428588,7518.700000000017,7595.421428571446,7672.142857142857

When num = 100, split1 **misses the last one**, but split2 not(which is my expection).When num is other num, e.t. 130, split1 and split2 get the sample result.
What's the reason to casuse the difference?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the usual [floating point inaccuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004).

Look, how the `max` comes out differently after dividing and multiplicating it back:

```
scala> 7672.142857142857 / 100 * 100
res1: Double = 7672.142857142858
```

And this number is larger than `max`, so it doesn't fit into the range:

```
scala> max / bucketNum * bucketNum > max
res2: Boolean = true
```

It's still more correct than adding the `step` 100 hundred times in `splitsBucket2`:

```
scala> var result = 0.0
result: Double = 0.0

scala> for (_ <- 0 until 100) result += (max - min) / bucketNum

scala> result
res4: Double = 7672.142857142875
```

This is larger than both `max` and `max / bucketNum * bucketNum`. You avoid this in `splitBuckets2` by explicitly assigning `rst(num) = max` though.

---

You can try the following split implementation:

```
def splitsBucket3(min: Double, max: Double, num: Int): Array[Double] = {
  val step = (max - min) / num
  Array.tabulate(num + 1)(min + step * _)
}
```

It is guaranteed to have the correct number of elements, and has less numeric precision problems than `splitsBucket2`.

Comment: Thanks @Kolmar at first. Hoever, the last result of splitsBucket1 is 7595.421428571429, which is a step distance (about 76.72) to the **max**, It seems not the  problem of accuracy.

Comment: @bourneli The last *missing* element. It is missing because it's larger then `max`. Try to run `(min to (max + 1) by ((max - min) / num)).toArray`, you'll see it